# Compute $\int_\Gamma \frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z-1}dz$, where $\Gamma$ is the circle $|z-1|\le\frac{3}{2}$, positively oriented.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, complex-integration

> Compute $\int_\Gamma \frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z-1}dz$, where $\Gamma$ is the circle $|z-1|\le\frac{3}{2}$, positively oriented.

The numerator is not analytic in $\Gamma$ so we can't use Cauchy integral formula. I'm thinking maybe I shold use residue theorem. But then I have these two questions:

1. Should I look for the Laurent series of $e^\frac{1}{z}$ around $z=0$? What if I look for the series around some other points in $\Gamma$?
2. After I find the Laurent series of $e^\frac{1}{z}$, how do I find the Laurent series for the $\frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residue in the essential singularity can be computed trough Taylor's expansions:
$$e^{\frac{1}{z}}=1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+\ldots,$$
$$\frac{1}{z-1}=-1-z-z^2-z^3-\ldots,$$
from which (just multiply the two series):
$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-1},z=0\right)=-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k!}=\color{red}{1-e}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Just a follow-up, we do need these two series to converge uniformly to ensure that we can multiply term by term?

Comment: Yes. They both are absolutely convergent as soon as $|z|>1$. We have to enlarge a bit the original contour in order to include some set $\{z:|z|\leq 1+\varepsilon\}$, but this doesn't really matter since the only singularities are in $z=0$ and $z=1$.

Comment: There are two residues ,one is when z=0, and another one is when z=1

Comment: Jack, note that $\frac{1}{z-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ near $z=0$.  Hence, the reside at $0$ is $-\sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}=1-e\ne 1$.  Therefore, the sum of both residues is $1$.

Comment: I've posted a solution to clarify.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: you're right, now fixed, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{1/z}}{z-1}$.

We can expand $e^{1/z}$ and $\frac{1}{z-1}$ in the series

$$e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^n}$$

for $|z|>0$ and

$$\frac{1}{z-1}=-\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m$$

for $|z|<1$.  Then, we can write

$$f(z)=-\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{m-n}}{n!}\tag 1$$

for $0<|z|<1$.

---

The residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is the coefficient of the series in $(1)$ when $m-n=-1$.  This reveals

$$\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=0\right)=-\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+1)!}=1-e$$

---

The residue at $z=1$ is trivially seen to be $e$ and the sum of the residues is $1-e+e=1$.

---

Putting it all together, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\oint_{|z-1|=3/2}\frac{e^{1/z}}{z-1}\,dz=2\pi i}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

There are two resides Z=1 and Z=0,
when z=1, it's simple Res($e^{1\over z}\over {z-1}$,z=1)=e
when z=0,
since $${1\over {z-1}}=-{(1+z+z^{2}+...+z^{n}...)}$$
and $e^{1\over z}$=1+1/z+...
so Res($e^{1\over z}\over {z-1}$,z=0)=-1,
so the answer :2$\pi$i(e-1)

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ near $z=0$.  Hence, the reside at $0$ is $-\sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}=1-e\ne 1$.  Therefore, the sum of both residues is $1$.

Comment: I've posted a solution to clarify.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

It can be evaluated by the [residue at infnity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) trick...

Since the outside of the counter contains no singularity,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz&=-2\pi i\left(Res_{z=\infty}f(z)\right)\\
&=-2\pi i\left(Res_{z=0}f(z)-\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})\right)\\
&=-2\pi i\left(Res_{z=0}-\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{e^z}{z^{-1}-1}\right)\\
&=-2\pi i\left(Res_{z=0}\frac{e^z}{z(z-1)}\right)\\
&=-2\pi i\left(\left.\frac{e^z}{z-1}\right\rvert_{z=0}\right)\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$