# Find the residue of $\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-1)^2}$ at $z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Find the residue of $\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-1)^2}$ at $z=0$.

How to obtain Laurent Series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute $\int_\Gamma \frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{z-1}dz$, where $\Gamma$ is the circle $|z-1|\le\frac{3}{2}$, positively oriented.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066886/compute-int-gamma-frace-frac1zz-1dz-where-gamma-is-the-circle)

Comment: @S717717 It isn't a duplicate of the question you suggested.  Note that here, the denominator is a quadratic.

Comment: @Dr.MV But similar like that..

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{1/z}}{(z-1)^2}$.

We can expand $e^{1/z}$ and $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$ in the series

$$e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^n}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+1)z^m$$

Then, we can write

$$f(z)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(m+1)z^{m-n}}{n!}\tag 1$$

The residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is the coefficient of the series in $(1)$ when $m-n=-1$.  This reveals

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=0\right)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}=e}$$

---

**NOTE:**

We can express $(1)$ as a Laurent series by writing

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(m+1)z^{m-n}}{n!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{p=-\infty}^m \frac{(m+1)z^{p}}{(m-p)!}\\\\
&\sum_{p=-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_{m=p}^\infty \frac{m+1}{(m-p)!}\right)\,z^p\tag 2
\end{align}$$

From $(2)$ we can see that the coefficient on the term $z^{-1}$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(f(z), z=0\right)&=\sum_{m=-1}^\infty \frac{m+1}{(m+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m+1}{(m+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}\\\\
&=e
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark